# How to tell Python to look into a different directory for modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've recently started working on Python and our organization's admin team doesn't usually update third-party modules located in the global site-packages directory.

So, I created a separate folder like a virtual environment and installed the latest version of the third-party module.  Even after trying the *sys.path.append* adding the new directory, the script is still loading the old module from the default location.

How do I force my Python script to look into a specific folder for modules but not into the default directory (We're on Linux) ?

Comment: Try using `sys.path.insert(0, path)` instead of `sys.path.append(path)`.

Comment: Can't you work with a real virtual environment?

Comment: Learn how to use your software.  And if you're not building in an actual virtual environment, and you're getting paid to do this, then your company isn't doing it right.  Engineers working with their own private folders would not survive a code review in a proper engineering shop.

Comment: `sys.path.append` puts the new directory at the _end_ of the search path, so of course it still finds the old one first.

Answer (score 3):

Python searches for modules in `sys.path`'s locations in the exact order they're listed, so when it finds a module matching the name inside *site-packages* it doesn't go further.

You can simply push the directory at the beginning of `sys.path` so your folder will be searched first.

```
sys.path.insert(0, new_path)
```